# Automator apple operation not permitted while trying to access volumes

Tags: macos, automator

I'm trying to write an Automator that outputs a .csv that represents all the directories and subdirectories with relative disk usage in an external drive, the problem is I only get "operation not permitted" even if I'm under sudo.

here is my appleScript:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set volumename to first item of input
    set filename to second item of input

    do shell script "sudo du -h /Volumes/" & volumename & "/  > " & quoted form of (POSIX path of (path to desktop)) & "" & filename & ".csv" with administrator privileges

end run
```

I've already tried to give full disk permissions to my test.app but doesn't work.

Comment: 1) `sudo` is irrelevant/redundant here, since `with administrator privileges` already runs the command as root. 2) You may be running into system areas that're protected by System Integrity Protection (SIP); what are the specific errors you get?

Comment: @GordonDavisson literally only "operation not permitted", and im scanning an external usb drive.